# how to disable vs code toast feature

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, rust-analyzer

The toast notifications (popups) of VS Code is surprisingly annoying. These notifications are often redundant and cluttering as well as visually distracting.

I know this has been asked before and wondering if there is anything new as of 2022. Managing the noise is a requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom right corner of the screen should display a bell icon. When you select that you can turn it to Do Not Disturb mode and that means there will be no new notifications within VS Code, except for ones related to errors.

Comment: Thank. I was able to stop the notifications it seems. Unfortunately, I inadvertently caused the Bell icon to disappear. Any thoughts on how to get it back? :)

Comment: Oh, no! Is it just the bell icon or is the whole blue status bar missing now? If it's the whole bar, you can select view>appearance>status bar to get it displayed again.

Comment: Just the bell. I don't know what it's called and "bell" doesn't seem to be it. :)

Comment: It might be "Do Not Disturb Mode" or "Zen Mode"...which is confusing. I see Zen Mode used in Settings and Do Not Disturb Mode in the mouse over for the icon.